# Swift cannot determine switch clauses being exhaustive

Tags: swift

This is an artificial problem because I want to learn about swift in more detail.
The swift compiler complains about the following not being exhaustive.  Surely in the general case, it cannot determine if the case statements are exhaustive.  How best should I
tell the compiler my list is exhaustive, such as in the following case?

```
let point = (2, 2) 

switch point {    
    case let (x, y) where x == y:
        println("on the x=y line")
    case let (x, y) where x != y:
        println("somewhere else off x=y line") 
}
```

Is the only option to add empty default: cases?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the only option to add empty default: cases?

At this point, yes. It's a compiler bug which we, at the moment, must work around. If I were you, I would certainly [file a Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) detailing your finds.

Comment: It might not end up being a "compiler bug" that will ever get fixed. With operator overloading it is possible to create types where neither `==` or `!=` will return `true` for the same two operands.

Comment: I have filed a radar as suggested; see 17568787.

Comment: Apple has reported back on the bug 17568787.  It is closed because to resolve it would require a constraint solver but that would adversely affect compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm studying Swift and I've found following solution to your brief snippet:

```
let point = (2, 2)

switch point {
case let (x, y) where x == y:
    print("on the x=y line")
case let (x, y): // Otherwise where x != y:
    print("somewhere else off x=y line")
}
```

I know, it's not a solution to exhaustivity check made by the compiler but it's a way to avoid the useless `default` clause.